# No such file or directory while compiling GCC code

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to compile an application, however, when I use the `./configure` command, it presents me with:

```
config.status: executing depfiles commands
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/auth.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/channel.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/channel_mode.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/client.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/conf.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/conf_class.Po: No such file or directory
./config.status: line 1510: src/./.deps/conf_db.Po: No such file or directory
```

Along with several more strings of files that it seems to perceive as not existing. I've checked and there are files of these names in their respective folders. I have also done my best to make sure I have all of the dependencies installed.

And when I try to make it, I see:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/c/users/Jeremy/Desktop/eircd-hybrid8.3/libltdl'
/bin/bash ../libtool --silent  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -no-undefined -dlpreopen dlopen.la   -o libltdlc.la  loaders/libltdlc_la-preopen.lo libltdlc_la-lt__alloc.lo libltdlc_la-lt_dlloader.lo libltdlc_la-lt_error.lo libltdlc_la-ltdl.lo libltdlc_la-slist.lo lt__strl.lo -lcrypt
ar: /mnt/c/users/Jeremy/Desktop/eircd-hybrid8.3/libltdl/./.libs/dlopen.a: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [libltdlc.la] Error 9
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/c/users/Jeremy/Desktop/eircd-hybrid8.3/libltdl'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/c/users/Jeremy/Desktop/eircd-hybrid8.3/libltdl'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/c/users/Jeremy/Desktop/eircd-hybrid8.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I doing something wrong that I'm not seeing? I'm compiling using bash in Windows 10 if that helps, although as I understand it, it shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: Are you running an Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows 10? I'm not seeing why Ubuntu applies to this question.

Comment: This is native bash using Ubuntu as a base, as part of the new Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Currently in Insider builds).